Best Practices for Managing Projects with Multiple Phases in Jira?
In our organization, we use Jira for project management. Our issue hierarchy in Jira starts with "Request," followed by "Epic," "Story," and "Subtasks." We primarily use the "Request" issue type to track overall project progress and timeline. Typically, we create Epic tickets as children of Request tickets for each module, with the overall project timeline updated in the Request ticket.
However, for projects with larger modules completed in phases, we use the same "Request" ticket and create a "Subtask" for each module. Each phase may have an uncertain end date, known only when development for the next phase begins. Since we track the timeline in the main "Request" ticket, project leaders may need to update it with the latest date.
Internally, we've implemented metrics that deduct points when the development team changes the timeline during the development phase, affecting project marks. From a project management perspective, what's the best practice for managing projects with multiple phases?

Can you give an example of the multiple phases you mention?

All projects have multiple phases. It's not very clear what you are asking,  but it seems to me that you are talking about releases. You have projects that may need a few releases to be completed and you track them in tickets. Is that it? Are you asking how to track releases using hierarchical tickets? Please elaborate on your question or provide examples for the community to better understand what you need help with.

Hi @BartvanIngenSchenau & Bogdan, appreciate your feedback on my post. The various phases can also be considered as larger modules destined for deployment in production. These modules are integral parts of the project. For instance, in a website revamp project, each module is substantial and requires deployment individually. What are the best practices for handling or organizing this type of project within the organization?

As I already mentioned in my comment, to me this looks like Jira releases. You have a project with phases as you call them, or modules, each module being substantial and requiring deployment individually.
With Jira releases, what you do is:

create a version in Jira. This is to identify your release name under which you will group the work required. You could call this "Module XYZ - v1.0" or something.
schedule your issues in your version. The tickets that are part of "Module XYZ - v1.0" you will mark as such.
you can assign release dates if needed.
you will work on your tickets and at any point you want to see what's happening with "Module XYZ - v1.0" you look inside the relese to see which tickets are in which status.
when all tickets are done you can mark the version as released and deploy the module.
you can capture release notes for later, if you need them.

I did a quick search and this video explains some basics for managing releases with Jira.
https://youtube.com/watch?v=tQGnZKyrVYs
From there you might have more options. For example, if you use Jira Plans / Roadmaps, you can use your releases to better manage your efforts. The following is another short intro from doing a quick search.
https://youtube.com/watch?v=-j_b48oTWLE
The two videos should be enough to show where you can find these features in Jira and allow you to later learn more about them if you think this is the answer you were looking for.
